# Parsing non-standard arguments

Tags: c, command-line-arguments

I am trying to create a program that replaces one or many characters from a source file with one or many specified characters and writes the new text into a destination file.

For example, the following calls to the program "sub" all result in replacing instances of 'a' and 'b' from src.txt with 'x' and 'y' respectively and writes it to dest.txt.

```
$ sub --ab -+xy -i src.txt -o dest.txt 
$ sub -i src.txt -o dest.txt --ab -+xy
$ sub -o dest.txt --ab -i src.txt -+xy
$ sub --ab -o dest.txt -+xy -i src.txt
```

I have looked at C's getopt() but I don't think it covers possible multiple characters following options.

The way the program accepts arguments is fixed. How would I parse these arguments in which some cases may have multiple letters to replace in a text file? And handle any argument ordering?

I cannot switch on strings, but I cannot create enum with special characters featured in the options. As far as I know getopt() doesn't handle the way my program expects arguments. So I'm left with the following very incomplete code:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {

    // help message displayed for "sub" and "sub -h"
    if (argc == 1 || strcmp(argv[1], "-h") == 0){
        helpMsg();
    } else {
        // process rest of argv
        int i = 2;
        while (argc != 0) {

            char *opt = argv[i];

            switch(opt){

            }

            i++;
            argc--;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *How would I parse these arguments* - well... manually, if you can't think of a way of making it `getopt`-friendly.

Comment: Just use `argc` and `argv`. But I would strongly recommend against weird non-standard ways to pass arguments. Don't annoy users.

Comment: I tried creating a while loop with the condition while (args !=0) and then thought that I could switch on each argv[i] and manually handle each case that way but switch only works on ints. Then I tried creating an enum, but C enums don't handle special characters that my arguments have like "--"

Comment: See also the previous (closed) iteration of this question: [How do I capture arguments and perform necessary operations using C's "int main(int argc, char** argv)"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70991250/how-do-i-capture-arguments-and-perform-necessary-operations-using-cs-int-main)

Comment: @Cheatah I agree the way the program accepts args is frustrating, but assuming it cannot be changed, how would I do this?

Comment: If you have a specific code you want to fix, you should post it. "How would I do this" is not a question that is going to be answered here.

Comment: `--ab` and `-+xy` will confuse any longtime Linux users. Or at least, they confuse me. It's not only nonstandard syntax, it flagrantly violates the convention that `-` is for short options and `--` for long options. According to that convention, `--ab` should be an option named "ab", and `-+xy` should be shorthand for `-+ -x -y`.

Comment: As you were told before, you're going to have to set up some variables — for the input file, output file, search characters and replace characters. You then iterate over each of the arguments passed to your program, checking what it contains and translating it appropriately. The `-+` and `--` notations make this obnoxious and non-standard, but presumably that's not your fault and your teacher intended you to have to do the work longhand. And you are correct that neither (POSIX) `getopt()` nor any standard variant will handle this notation — that's what 'non-standard' means in this context.

Comment: Yes, you need to loop over the args.  No, you can't switch on strings.  But you can use an if/else ladder, with a bunch of `strcmp` calls.

Comment: You can switch on *characters* just fine, though.  If the first character of `argv[i]` is `'-'`, you can probably getting away with switching on the second character, which it looks like is going to be `'-'`, `'+'`, `'i'`, or `'o'`.  And note that for `'i'` and `'o'`, you're going to "consume" an argument without doing the `-+io` thing.

Comment: @JohnKugelman: OP clearly stated “The way the program accepts arguments is fixed.” They have external constraints that are not part of this question, and comments arguing against them are irrelevant and unhelpful.

Comment: The presented examples look fairly simple to parse. In a loop checking arguments, check if the first character of the current argument is `-`. If it is not, report an error for an unrecognized argument. If it is, switch on the next character. If it is `i`, set a pointer for the input file name to the next argument, and skip the next argument. (If that pointer is already set to non-null, after having been initialized to null, report a duplicate argument.) If it is `o`, do the same for an output file name pointer. If it is `-`, do the same for a pointer for the characters to be replaced…

Comment: … If it is `+`, do the same for a pointer for the replacement characters. If it is none of those, report an error for an unrecognized argument. Be sure not to overrun `argv` when skipping arguments, as might happen if the user enters `-i` as the last argument without a name after it. Also note that the pointers for the input and output files point to the next argument, which is skipped, but the pointers for the characters point into the current argument, and the next argument is not skipped.

Answer (score 2):

Although it is highly unorthodox, this code works on a Mac:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int opt;
    while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "i:o:+:-:")) != -1)
    {
        switch (opt)
        {
        case '+':
        case '-':
        case 'i':
        case 'o':
            printf("Got '-%c' argument '%s'\n", opt, optarg);
            break;
        default:
            printf("!! FAIL !! optopt = %c\n", optopt);
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It tells `getopt()` that `-` is an option 'letter' (character) that expects an argument, and that `+` is an option character that expects an argument.  I can run it like this (code in `getopt23.c` compiled to `getopt23`):

```
$ ./getopt23 -i input -o output --ab -+xy
Got '-i' argument 'input'
Got '-o' argument 'output'
Got '--' argument 'ab'
Got '-+' argument 'xy'
$
```

Note that that the compulsory space between `-i` and the input file etc is not mandatory with this code:

```
$ ./getopt23 -iinput -ooutput -+ xy --ab
Got '-i' argument 'input'
Got '-o' argument 'output'
Got '-+' argument 'xy'
Got '--' argument 'ab'
$ ./getopt23 -iinput -ooutput -+ xy -- ab
Got '-i' argument 'input'
Got '-o' argument 'output'
Got '-+' argument 'xy'
$
```

The second of these two is interesting — the `--` indicates the end of the options and the `ab` is a non-option argument (typically a file name).  If the code was extended with a loop:

```
for (int i = optind; i < argc; i++)
    printf("Plain argument %d: '%s'\n", i, argv[i]);
```

then the `ab` (but not the `--`) would be printed as a 'plain argument'.  (The POSIX [Utility Syntax Guidelines](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html#tag_12_02) use the name 'operand' for what I called 'non-option arguments' .)

If you write your own code, you can enforce the 'file name separate from option' and 'replacement string attached to `--` or `-+` option'.  With regular `getopt()`, it is fiendishly difficult to do that without incurring undefined behaviour.

---

I previously [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70993300/parsing-non-standard-arguments/70993524#comment125501419_70993300) that:

> And you are correct that neither (POSIX) [`getopt()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/getopt.html) nor any standard variant will handle this notation — that's what 'non-standard' means in this context.

I have to partially withdraw that statement.  If you must have the `-i` and the input file name in separate arguments and not presented as `-iinput`, and similarly with `-o` and the output file name, and if the character sets must be attached to `--` and `-+`, then you cannot use `getopt()` reliably.  If that notation can be flexible, you can use `getopt()` after all and my previous comment is an over-statement.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the simplest thing is just to initialize your options in a loop, testing for each case.

```
#include <iso646.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int help_quit( const char * message )
{
  printf( "%s\n", message );
  exit( 0 );
}

int main( int argc, char ** argv )
{
  FILE       * infile       = NULL;
  FILE       * outfile      = NULL;
  const char * in_filename  = NULL;
  const char * out_filename = NULL;
  const char * to_remove    = "";
  const char * to_add       = "";
  
  for (int n = 1;  n < argc;  n += 1)
  {
    // All arguments must begin with '-'
    if (argv[n][0] != '-') 
    {
      help_quit( "All arguments must begin with a dash" );
    }
    
    // -h, --help
    if ((strcmp( argv[n], "-h" ) == 0) or (strcmp( argv[n], "--help" ) == 0))
    {
      help_quit( "usage:\n  sub ..." );
    }
    
    // -i FILENAME
    if (strcmp( argv[n], "-i" ) == 0)
    {
      if (argc-n < 2) help_quit( "missing input filename" );
      in_filename = argv[++n];
      continue;
    }
    
    // -o FILENAME
    if (strcmp( argv[n], "-o" ) == 0)
    {
      if (argc-n < 2) help_quit( "missing output filename" );
      out_filename = argv[++n];
      continue;
    }
    
    if (argv[n][1] == '-')
    {
      to_remove = argv[n] + 2;
      continue;
    }
    
    if (argv[n][1] == '+')
    {
      to_add = argv[n] + 2;
      continue;
    }
    
    help_quit( "unknown option" );
  }
  
  // validate args
  if (strlen( to_remove ) != strlen( to_add )) help_quit( "number of remove chars != number of add chars" );
  if (!in_filename)  help_quit( "you must specify an input filename" );
  if (!out_filename) help_quit( "you must specify an output filename" );
  if (!(infile  = fopen( in_filename,  "r" ))) help_quit( "could not open input file" );
  if (!(outfile = fopen( out_filename, "w" ))) 
  {
    fclose( infile );
    help_quit( "could not open output file" );
  }
  
  // do stuff
  printf( "%s\n", "TO DO" );
  
  // clean up
  fclose( outfile );
  fclose( infile );
  return 0;
}
```